# Adding AD group to another AD group powershell script

Tags: windows, powershell, windows-server-2012

When a server gets created an AD group gets created that has the server name in it (xxxServerNamexxx).
I have a pre-written script to install IIS locally on the server.
At the end of the install I want to add an AD group to the server AD group.
The server's AD group name is like this xxxServerNamexxx  where xxx would be a static but different values (front xxx compared to back xxx) , for example it would be like this abcServerNamedef and the values for xxx won't change.
I'm trying to do something like this adding the xxx in front and back of the server name:

```
ADD-ADGroupMember "abc$env:COMPUTERNAME$def" –members "MyADgrouptoAdd"
```

I can't get it to output xxxServerNamexxx correctly so the script fails.

Comment: Since we cannot debug the script for you can you insert breakpoints and provide some debugging values?

Comment: Where do you define the back `$def` from? The way you have it written should work fine if that variable is ok

Answer (score 0):

## A couple things

1. For the string name of the computer object (`MyADgrouptoAdd`), be sure to append a `$`
   to the end of it within those same double quotes (i.e. `"MyADgrouptoAdd$")`—assuming this is really a computer object account of a domain joined computer/server.
2. For the concatenated AD group object (`abc$env:COMPUTERNAME$def`) name compromised of computer
   name environmental variable, another variable, and a string,
   encapsulate the variables using subexpression operators e.g.
   `$($variable)`, `"abc$($env:COMPUTERNAME)$($def)"`, etc.

### PowerShell examples

```
Add-ADGroupMember -Identity "abc$($env:COMPUTERNAME)$($def)" -Members "ComputerName$"
```

or

```
$Group = "My Group Name";
$List = (Get-ADComputer -Filter * -Properties *) | ? {$_.Name -like "*xxx*"} | % {$_.Name};
$List | % { Add-ADGroupMember -Identity $Group -Members "$($_)$" };
```

---

### Supporting Resources

- [PowerShell Operators $( ) @( ) :: &](https://ss64.com/ps/syntax-operators.html)
- [ForEach-Object](https://ss64.com/ps/foreach-object.html)

  > Standard [Aliases](https://ss64.com/ps/get-alias.html) for Foreach-Object: the '`%`' symbol, ForEach